# appmaildev DKIM test fails permerror(no key)

Tags: email, dns, dkim

I'm trying to configure DKIM for my mail server and appmaildev keeps failing the DKIM test with the following error:

```
============================================================
DKIM result: permerror (no key)
============================================================
Signed by: daniel@dgriffen.com
Expected Body Hash: 47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
```

The Signature in the message header looks like this:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mail.dgriffen.com;
s=mail; t=1412713480;
bh=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=;
h=To:Subject:Date:From:From;
b=ZX2a8kFI6/n1ctLv+sqNsm/PNSdV2sWa55uFRpNHJZ9Pya4HGa5otONWRITzIM1R3
 UYoI3R2quVvdccazK3Ii2H5iwcZqOILV4qLIbxWQTheI5VG0XZ7gqzVMHQFjM5iv1G
 JMgJe2fDzbHNZr1noxvNv2Ww3G/FwBqYA8vUc0+w=
```

My DNS DKIM record is as follows:

```
nslookup -q=TXT mail._domainkey.dgriffen.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mail._domainkey.dgriffen.com    text = "v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDniqJ6/NqLk558P+oRaLBYMcsnK76nxGA1fzaMlYmnc8v9vcttbByt9joZ0Fa3u+EwIf13cs8L9kAK05hWnYqK045k9FNqbAVJvMPtcWff+EGJhO6zv8Cmzzst2HU3Q2s2NjFpTlDUXHU/6F6DOcVRRRMSkKWZ+rVrwKMYCmXScQIDAQAB\;"

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

As far as I can tell everything is set up properly. The correct selector is being used, which seems to be the most common error in cases like this. The value that the error report is returning is also expecting a value that is contained inside signature. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the issue. The tag d=mail.dgriffen.com needed to be dgriffen.com. This was an issue with the Keytable file for opendkim. If any of you followed the tutorial on ars technica on how to setup your own email server this is an issue present in that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue is a broken DNS record.

In my case I've put in TXT value:

```
v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; =MIIBIjANBgk...
```

instead of

```
v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgk...
```